# Address component type in google maps geocoding

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

this is a part of my geocoding code. I want it to show only country of the selected place, but it shows all address components, My problem is I cant specify the address components object. There is a way of doing it that is written on documentation but I didnt understand, can you do it for me.

```
 if (geocoder) {
                geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        var str = "";
                        $.each(results, function(){
                            str += "address components: <ul>"
                            $.each(this.address_components, function(){
                                str +="<li>"+this.types.join(", ")+": "+this.long_name+"</li>";
                            });
                            str +="</ul>";
                        });
                        $("#geocode_info").html(str);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need only country from the response that comes.
Need some work.Need to parse the json for country name.
Try following for geocoding response.

```
for(var addComponent in json.results[0].address_components){
    var component = json.results[0].address_components[addComponent];
    for(typeIndex in component.types ){
        if(component.types[typeIndex]=='country') {
            console.log(component.long_name);
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to double check your code, the type now appears to be missing on some address components.

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=3000+Australia&sensor=false